# Solving for x in a series equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Solve for x:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 7x^{5n} = 36 $$

Just curious as to how you would go about solving a problem like this? It looks as though differential equations come into play, and I'm assuming standard algebra rules are ruled out, where x has to be on one side of the equation. Anyway's, the fact that there's a variable x in the equation throws me into a rut because of the existence of n as well. Any kind of help on how to go about solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use the formula for the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}7x^{5n} = 36 \implies \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^{5n} = 36/7 => y = x^5; \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}y^{n} = 36/7 \implies $ ?????

Comment: Read up on Geometric Series: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite geometric series with $|r| < 1$ converges as follows:

$$ \sum_{k = m}^{\infty} ar^k = \frac{ar^m}{1 - r} $$

In your case, $r = x^5$, $a = 7$ and $m = 1$, so we can deduce the following:

\begin{align*}
\frac{7x^5}{1 - x^5} &= 36 \\
7x^5 &= 36(1 - x^5) \\
x &= \left(\frac{36}{43}\right)^{1/5}
\end{align*}

Comment: Excellent, so r stands as the common ratio, correct? And a is our constant in the equation. Just making sure.

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum _{n=1}^\infty 7x^{5n} =   \sum _{n=1}^\infty 7(x^{5})^n= \frac{7}{1-x^5} -7   $

$\frac{7}{1-x^5} -7 =36$

$x^5 = \frac{36}{43}     $

$x = (\frac{36}{43} )^{1/5}    $

Answer (score 1):

The sum converges iff $|x^5| < 1$, in which we have the closed form formula $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 7 x^{5n} = 7 \left( \frac{1}{1 - x^5} -1 \right)$, which then allows one to solve for $x$, yielding $x = \left (\frac{36}{43} \right)^{1/5}$.